# How to install Xgboost on macOS compiled with GPU Support?

Tags: python, macos, gpu, xgboost

I am trying to install xgboost integrated with GPU support, on my MacOS Mojave(10.14.6) from last 3 days, however, no success has been reached. I tried 2 approaches:

1. pip install xgboost

xgboost is installed here and it runs successfully without GPU option(i.e., without tree_method=’gpu_hist’).

I want to run with gpu_hist by giving “tree_method=’gpu_hist’ ” in tree parameters. When I gave “tree_method=’gpu_hist’ ” in tree parameters, following error has come:

```
XGBoostError: [12:10:34] /Users/travis/build/dmlc/xgboost/src/gbm/../common/common.h:153: XGBoost version not compiled with GPU support.
Stack trace:
[bt] (0) 1 libxgboost.dylib 0x000000012256ba60 dmlc::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal() + 112
[bt] (1) 2 libxgboost.dylib 0x00000001225f92b3 xgboost::gbm::GBTree::ConfigureUpdaters() + 531
[bt] (2) 3 libxgboost.dylib 0x00000001225f8b97 xgboost::gbm::GBTree::Configure(std::__1::vector<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > > > > const&) + 967
[bt] (3) 4 libxgboost.dylib 0x0000000122611a0c xgboost::LearnerConfiguration::Configure() + 1500
[bt] (4) 5 libxgboost.dylib 0x0000000122611e68 xgboost::LearnerImpl::UpdateOneIter(int, std::__1::shared_ptr) + 120
[bt] (5) 6 libxgboost.dylib 0x000000012256331d XGBoosterUpdateOneIter + 157
[bt] (6) 7 libffi.7.dylib 0x0000000102102ead ffi_call_unix64 + 85
[bt] (7) 8 ??? 0x00007ffeee291da0 0x0 + 140732894092704
```

2. My second approach:

   git clone –recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
   cd xgboost/
   make -j4
   cd python-package
   python3 setup.py install

   Though it installs xgboost, but throws following error whille running this statement:
   dtrain=xgb.DMatrix(df_train_features,label=df_train_label)#,missing=-999)

   AttributeError: dlsym(0x7ffe9aed62f0, XGDMatrixSetDenseInfo): symbol not found

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me due to *outdated* `libxgboost.so` that somehow wasn't updated during fresh install.

To resolve the issue and install `xgboost` with GPU support you should do something like:

```
# remove libxgboost.so manually from where it resides
rm /home/$USER/anaconda3/lib/libxgboost.so 
pip uninstall -y xgboost 
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost && mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. -DUSE_CUDA=ON
make -j12
cd ../python-package
python setup.py install
```